# How to read just words, not full phrases

Tags: python

I have code that reads from a text file, and prints out each line containing a keyword (entered from an input). However, the whole phrase entered gets searched, not the words by them selves. E.g. I will enter

> I have a fast car

The whole phrase is searched for in the file, not just keywords, such as fast, or car.

```
file = open("file.txt", "r")
search= input("What to be searched?  ")
for line in file:
    if search in line:
        print ("found" +line)

file.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
search = input("What to be searched?  ").split()

with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if any(word in line for word in search):
            print ("found" + line)
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers handled your immediate problem: searching for a word instead of a line.  However, you implied a more difficult problem: searching for **key** words.  I infer that when you enter "I have a fast car", you want to ignore the common words and search on only "fast" and "car".

This is not a trivial problem in natural language processing (NLP).  Some words are common in some contexts, but significant in others.  To simplify the problem, many applications have a list of "stop" words: those considered too trivial to use as keywords.  This turns your solution into something like this, modifying @Apero's code:

```
search = input("Enter search text:  ").split()
-- Remove trivial words from search list; add your own words to this.
stop_word = ["a", "an", "the", "am", "is", "are", "have", "has"]
search = [word not in stop_word for word in search]

with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if any(word in line for word in search):
            print ("found" + line)
```

Comment: yeah, I was also thinking of NLTK etc, I just stayed as close as possible from his code and didn't want to make too many changes.